# Trouble checking dynamic entity

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, entity, type-parameter

Greetings,

A old colleague of mine made this code:

```
public abstract class PagedViewModelBase<T> : PartnerViewModelBase, IPagedCollectionView where T : Entity, IEditableObject, new()
```

Now I want to check what the type/value is of T..   I've tried using  "`T is Model`
but it gives me the error "'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'".

How can I check if "T" is of a particular model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following check

```
typeof(T) == typeof(Model)
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thank you very much !  will accept as answer in 6 min

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can check it with this code

```
typeof(Model).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```